# ARKit – Raycasting using a world ray instead of a screen point

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, arcore, realitykit

I want to achieve something similar like [ARCore's raycast method](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/arcore/reference/com/google/ar/core/Frame#hitTest(float[],%20int,%20float[],%20int)) which takes an arbitrary ray in world space coordinates instead of a screen-space point:

```
List<HitResult> hitTest (float[] origin3, int originOffset, float[] direction3, int directionOffset)
```

I see ARKit itself has not that method like that, but in any way maybe someone has an idea!

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**In Apple RealityKit and ARKit frameworks you can find three main types of `Raycast` methods: `ARView Raycast`, `ARSession Raycast` and `Scene Raycast` (or World Raycast). All methods written in Swift:**

#### ARView.raycast(from:allowing:alignment:)

This instance method performs a ray cast, where a ray is cast into the scene from the center of the camera through a point in the view, and the results are immediately returned. You can use this type of raycast in ARKit.

```
func raycast(from point: CGPoint, 
        allowing target: ARRaycastQuery.Target, 
              alignment: ARRaycastQuery.TargetAlignment) -> [ARRaycastResult]
```

#### ARView.scene.raycast(origin:direction:query:mask:relativeTo:)

#### WORLD RAYCAST

This instance method performs a convex ray cast against all the geometry in the scene for a ray of a given origin, direction, and length.

```
func raycast(origin: SIMD3<Float>, 
          direction: SIMD3<Float>,
              query: CollisionCastQueryType, 
               mask: CollisionGroup, 
         relativeTo: Entity) -> [CollisionCastHit]
```

#### ARView.session.trackedRaycast(_:updateHandler:)

This instance method repeats a ray-cast query over time to notify you of updated surfaces in the physical environment. You can use this type of raycast in ARKit 3.5.

```
func trackedRaycast(_ query: ARRaycastQuery, 
              updateHandler: @escaping ([ARRaycastResult]) -> Void) -> ARTrackedRaycast?
```

#### ARView.trackedRaycast(from:allowing:alignment:updateHandler:)

This RealityKit's instance method also performs a tracked ray cast, but here a ray is cast into the scene from the center of the camera through a point in the view.

```
func trackedRaycast(from point: CGPoint, 
               allowing target: ARRaycastQuery.Target, 
                     alignment: ARRaycastQuery.TargetAlignment, 
                 updateHandler: @escaping ([ARRaycastResult]) -> Void) -> ARTrackedRaycast?
```

#### Code snippet 01:

```
import RealityKit

let startPosition: SIMD3<Float> = [3,-2,0]
let endPosition: SIMD3<Float> = [10,7,-5]
let query: CollisionCastQueryType = .all
let mask: CollisionGroup = .all

let raycasts: [CollisionCastHit] = arView.scene.raycast(from: startPosition, 
                                                          to: endPosition, 
                                                       query: query,  
                                                        mask: mask, 
                                                  relativeTo: nil)

guard let rayCast: CollisionCastHit = raycasts.first
else { 
    return 
}
```

#### Code snippet 02:

```
import ARKit

let query = arView.raycastQuery(from: screenCenter,
                            allowing: .estimatedPlane,
                           alignment: .any)

let raycast = session.trackedRaycast(query) { results in

    if let result = results.first {
        object.transform = result.transform
    } 
}

raycast.stop()
```