# RealityKit – Proper Hit-Testing in ARView

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, hittest, realitykit, usdz

I have a code like this one:

```
@objc func handleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    
    let tapLocation = sender.location(in: arView)
    
    let hitResult0 = scnView?.hitTest(tapLocation)

    if let hitResult = arView?.entity(at: tapLocation) {
         // ...
    }
}
```

**hitResult** gives a bad precision. It returns the same entity (`WheelbarrowHandles`) even if I tapped on a different smaller one.
**hitResult0** gives all object near to the tap location (to much).

ModelLoading:

```
self.theModel = try! Entity.load(named: "wheelborrow")
self.theModel?.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true)
```

Is it bad collision shapes generated?

**Updated**

I tried to do the next instead of generation:

```
modelEntity.collision = CollisionComponent(shapes: [ShapeResource.generateConvex(from: modelEntity.model!.mesh)])
```

and it works.

Comment: To find to how hit-testing and ray-casting works, look at this post – https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56466773/what-is-the-real-benefit-of-using-raycast-in-arkit-and-realitykit/56467767#56467767, at this post – https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56736645/hittest-prints-ar-entity-name-even-when-i-am-not-tapping-on-it/59866900#59866900 and at this one – https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60294367/how-to-use-raycast-methods-in-realitykit

Comment: Tnx, @AndyFedoroff . I'll try raycasting and writeback.

Answer (score 2):

Generated collision shapes:

```
generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true)
```

[image]

And with the next code:

```
modelEntity.collision = CollisionComponent(shapes: [ShapeResource.generateConvex(from: modelEntity.model!.mesh)])
```

[image]

Comment: This is amazing, thank you for this info!. Also how did u visualise the shape/wireframe? :O

Comment: debugOptions.insert(ARView.DebugOptions.showPhysics)