# How to use Raycast methods in RealityKit?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, raycasting, realitykit

There are three ways about Detecting Intersections in `RealityKit` framework, but I don't know how to use it in my project.

1.

```
func raycast(origin: SIMD3<Float>, 
          direction: SIMD3<Float>, 
             length: Float, 
              query: CollisionCastQueryType, 
               mask: CollisionGroup, 
         relativeTo: Entity?) -> [CollisionCastHit]
```

2.

```
func raycast(from: SIMD3<Float>, 
               to: SIMD3<Float>, 
            query: CollisionCastQueryType, 
             mask: CollisionGroup, 
       relativeTo: Entity?) -> [CollisionCastHit]
```

3.

```
func convexCast(convexShape: ShapeResource, 
               fromPosition: SIMD3<Float>, 
            fromOrientation: simd_quatf, 
                 toPosition: SIMD3<Float>, 
              toOrientation: simd_quatf, 
                      query: CollisionCastQueryType, 
                       mask: CollisionGroup, 
                 relativeTo: Entity?) -> [CollisionCastHit]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Simple Ray-Casting

If you want to find out how to position a model made in Reality Composer into a RealityKit scene (that has a detected horizontal plane) using Ray-Casting method, use the following code:

```
import RealityKit
import ARKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var arView: ARView!
    let scene = try! Experience.loadScene()
    
    @IBAction func onTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        
        scene.steelBox!.name = "Parcel"
        
        let tapLocation: CGPoint = sender.location(in: arView)
        let estimatedPlane: ARRaycastQuery.Target = .estimatedPlane
        let alignment: ARRaycastQuery.TargetAlignment = .horizontal
                
        let result: [ARRaycastResult] = arView.raycast(from: tapLocation,
                                                   allowing: estimatedPlane,
                                                  alignment: alignment)
        
        guard let rayCast: ARRaycastResult = result.first
        else { return }
        
        let anchor = AnchorEntity(world: rayCast.worldTransform)
        anchor.addChild(scene)
        arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)
        
        print(rayCast)
    }
}
```

Pay attention to a class `ARRaycastQuery`. This class comes from ARKit, not from RealityKit.

#### Convex-Ray-Casting

A Convex-Ray-Casting methods like `raycast(from:to:query:mask:relativeTo:)` is the op of swiping a convex shapes along a straight line and stopping at the very first intersection with any of the collision shape in the scene. Scene `raycast()` method performs a hit-tests against all entities with **`collision shapes`** in the scene. **Entities without a collision shape are ignored**.

You can use the [following code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74838015/how-to-change-models-color-on-tap-and-then-change-it-back-to-original/74840787#74840787) to perform a convex-ray-cast from start position to end:

```
import RealityKit

let startPosition: SIMD3<Float> = [0, 0, 0]
let endPosition: SIMD3<Float> = [5, 5, 5]
let query: CollisionCastQueryType = .all
let mask: CollisionGroup = .all

let raycasts: [CollisionCastHit] = arView.scene.raycast(from: startPosition, 
                                                          to: endPosition, 
                                                       query: query,  
                                                        mask: mask, 
                                                  relativeTo: nil)

guard let rayCast: CollisionCastHit = raycasts.first
else { return }
    
print(rayCast.distance)      /* The distance from the ray origin to the hit */
print(rayCast.entity.name)   /* The entity's name that was hit              */
```

A `CollisionCastHit` structure is a hit result of a collision cast and it lives in RealityKit's scene.

**P.S.**

When you use `raycast(from:to:query:mask:relativeTo:)` method **for measuring a distance from camera to entity** it doesn't matter what an **orientation** of ARCamera is, it only matters what its **position** is in world coordinates.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I am trying raycast to achieve this https://drive.google.com/file/d/12mgtPcbWPAGGPn0Fit9NKwDPXHqyass1/view?usp=sharing   How to track the center of the view and keep the object like in video, I have tried completion handler of raycast with .center in parameter. It does not move.

Comment: Yeah sure @andy

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68128026/use-raycast-to-keep-object-alway-in-front-of-screen-and-keep-changing-the-distan Here is the question. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm just curious that when using `convexCast(convexShape:fromPosition:fromOrientation:toPosition:toOrientation:query:mask:relativeTo:)` method we should provide `fromOrientation` and  `toOrientation`, but what orientation does the convex have when the position is not fromPosition and toPosition?Maybe RealityKit just automatically interpolate the orientation?