# RealityKit – Keep object always in front of screen

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

I am using the below code to keep the object in front of a screen and to move it with the camera. On `didUpdate frame: ARFrame` delegate I call getCameraPosition().
All is working perfect,
Now I need an efficient solution to improve processing time. In the current solution, I feel that the phone hangs sometimes. And what if existingPlaneInfinite & estimatedPlane are not available?
Here is the video [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12mgtPcbWPAGGPn0Fit9NKwDPXHqyass1/view) of what I have done.

```
  extension ARView {
        
        func getCameraPosition(from: CGPoint? = nil) -> Position {
            
            let from = from ?? self.center
            var result: ARRaycastResult?
            if let raycast = self.raycast(from: from,
                                          allowing: .existingPlaneInfinite,
                                          alignment: .horizontal).last {
                result = raycast
            } else if let raycast = self.raycast(from: from,
                                                 allowing: .estimatedPlane,
                                                 alignment: .horizontal).last {
                result = raycast
            }
            return result?.worldTransform.getPosition() ?? .zero
            
        }
    }

func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {
     
        if self.viewModel.isFirstHorizontalPlanDetected {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.object.position =  self.arView.currentPositionOfCamera()
            }
        }           
    }
```

Comment: "On didUpdateFrame delegate I call getCameraPosition()"  Que!?  Where?

Comment: I am not getting you. I get new position on each call of didUpdate frame delegate. You can see the code in question.

Comment: if you store the `self.center` value you probably don't need to switch to the main thread. Other than that, using ARRaycastQuery as @andy-fedoroff suggested is the way to go

Comment: Right @maxxfrazer

Comment: @maxxfrazer, thank you for your stories on Medium. They are amazing ))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution in this case is to use `trackedRaycast` method:

```
let query: ARRaycastQuery = .init(origin: SIMD3<Float>(),
                               direction: SIMD3<Float>(),
                                allowing: .estimatedPlane,
                               alignment: .horizontal)

let repeated = arView.session.trackedRaycast(query) { results in
 
    guard let result: ARRaycastResult = results.first
    else { return }
        
    let anchor = AnchorEntity(world: result.worldTransform)
    anchor.addChild(model)
    arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)
}
    
repeated?.stopTracking()
```

Also, you have to implement `ray(through:)` instance method:

```
@MainActor func ray(through screenPoint: CGPoint) -> (origin: SIMD3<Float>, 
                                                   direction: SIMD3<Float>)?
```

Comment: I have already tried this. I want to move the object's distance with the phone's movement. If you see the link given in the question, the Object goes far and comes nearer while I tilt the phone up and down.

Comment: Stackoverflow did not give me the notification for this updated answer.

Comment: Do I need to do it on each frame?

Comment: https://ibb.co/pXqvh2K It does not move the pipe. Tried by removing repeated?.stopTracking() as well.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/environmental_analysis/placing_objects_and_handling_3d_interaction

Comment: Thanks for the link, It has treasure. As I can see, They also update the square on each frame.  Direct raycast and using a query : does query enhance the performance ?