# How can I create a deep copy of a RealityKit Material in Swift?

Tags: swift, realitykit

What I'm trying to achieve is:

1. User selects object
2. Object changes material to indicate that it's selected
3. Object changes back to original material after it's deselected

The process I have now is:

activeObjectMaterials = detectedTaggedEntity.model.model!.materials[0] // Stores object material

detectedTaggedEntity.model.model?.materials = [highlightMaterial] // Object material changes to indicate highlight - works properly

detectedTaggedEntity.model.model?.materials = [activeObjectMaterials] // Object material SHOULD change back, but since the material is stored as a reference, it changed when we highlighted it, and the activeObjectMaterials is no longer the original value

The materials are all procedurally generated at runtime, so the approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75179451/swapping-materials-on-a-modelentity-in-realitykit?noredirect=1&lq=1) doesn't work.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74838015/how-to-change-models-color-on-tap-and-then-change-it-back-to-original/74840787#74840787) post may be helpful.