# How to put an anchor on reconstructed mesh to get accuracy

Tags: ios, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit, lidar

I am exploring lidar and its feature in ARKit. I am thinking of raycast position(x,y) on the lidar mesh. That means I want to put an anchor on the lidar mesh for the raycasted position.
The goal is to keep anchor objects sticky and accurate on surface/mesh. Below image gives better understanding

[image]

How to get Mesh position instead of default ARWorld position in raycast. That means, How to put anchor or box upon specific position of mesh/ARMeshAnchor?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @AndyFedoroff On mesh/using lidar, I want to put anchor at tapped/raycasted position.  another way I can say, How to raycast mesh position using the center point of screen

Comment: If we raycast in ARKit, We get a position in the context of the plane, I want to check if there is mesh data available then put the anchor on it instead of raycasted position.

Comment: For better result ask just one question per post.))) Insert the first question into this post and second question into another one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56466773/what-is-the-real-benefit-of-using-raycast-in-arkit-and-realitykit/56467767#56467767

Comment: I do have only one question, How to get Mesh position instead of default ARWorld position in raycast. That means, How to put anchor or box upon specific position of mesh/ARMeshAnchor.

Comment: The same way as usually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works with any LiDAR's reconstructed mesh, not only with planes:

```
@objc func tapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    
    let tapLocation = sender.location(in: arView)
    
    if let result: ARRaycastResult = arView.raycast(from: tapLocation,
                                                allowing: .estimatedPlane,
                                               alignment: .any).first {
        
        let resultAnchor = AnchorEntity(world: result.worldTransform)
        
        resultAnchor.addChild(self.sphereObject(0.05, .systemRed))
        
        arView.scene.addAnchor(resultAnchor, removerAfter: 10.0)
    }
}
```