# How to set a known position and orientation as a starting point of ARKit

Tags: swift, computer-vision, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

I am starting to use ARKit and I have a use case where I want to know the motion from a known position to another one.

So I was wondering if it is possible (like every tracking solution) to set a known position and orientation a starting point of the tracking in ARKit?

Regards

Comment: check position, rotation , orientation and eulerangles property https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/1408026-position Thre are sample source code available on git to calculate the length/distance

Comment: Can you please clarify what is meant by "known position"? Do you mean: a marker image; a node with relation to the scene's world origin; a specific geo location; a node on a flat plane? or a specific location within a "mapped" environment?

Answer (score 5):

There are at least six approaches allowing you set a starting point for a model. But using no [ARAnchors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52893075/what-is-aranchor-exactly/52899502#52899502) at all in your ARScene is considered as bad AR experience (although Apple's Augmented Reality app template has no any ARAnchors in a code).

#### First approach

This is the approach that Apple engineers propose us in `Augmented Reality app` template in Xcode. This approach doesn't use anchoring, so all you need to do is to accommodate a model in air with coordinates like `(x: 0, y: 0, z: -0.5)` or in other words your model will be 50 cm away from camera.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    sceneView.scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/ship.scn")!
    let model = sceneView.scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "ship", 
                                                recursively: true)
    model?.position.z = -0.5
    sceneView.session.run(ARWorldTrackingConfiguration())
}
```

#### Second approach

Second approach is almost the same as the first one, except it uses ARKit's anchor:

```
guard let sceneView = self.view as? ARSCNView 
else { return }

if let currentFrame = sceneView.session.currentFrame {
        
    var translation = matrix_identity_float4x4
    translation.columns.3.z = -0.5
    let transform = simd_mul(currentFrame.camera.transform, translation)
        
    let anchor = ARAnchor(transform: transform)
    sceneView.session.add(anchor: anchor)
}
```

#### Third approach

You can also create a pre-defined model's position pinned with ARAnchor using third approach, where you need to import RealityKit module as well:

```
func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate anchors: [ARAnchor]) {
            
    let model = ModelEntity(mesh: MeshResource.generateSphere(radius: 1.0))

    // ARKit's anchor
    let anchor = ARAnchor(transform: simd_float4x4(diagonal: [1,1,1]))
    
    // RealityKit's anchor based on position of ARAnchor
    let anchorEntity = AnchorEntity(anchor: anchor)

    anchorEntity.addChild(model)
    arView.scene.anchors.append(anchorEntity)
}
```

#### Fourth approach

If you turned on a plane detection feature you can use `Raycasting` or `Hit-testing` methods. As a target object you can use a little sphere (located at `0, 0, 0`) that will be raycasted.

```
let query = arView.raycastQuery(from: screenCenter,
                            allowing: .estimatedPlane,
                           alignment: .any)

let raycast = session.trackedRaycast(query) { results in

    if let result = results.first {
        object.transform = result.transform
    } 
}
```

#### Fifth approach

This approach is focused to save and share ARKit's [WorldMaps](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arworldmap).

```
func writeWorldMap(_ worldMap: ARWorldMap, to url: URL) throws {

    let data = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: worldMap, 
                                         requiringSecureCoding: true)
    try data.write(to: url)
}

func loadWorldMap(from url: URL) throws -> ARWorldMap {

    let mapData = try Data(contentsOf: url)
    guard let worldMap = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: ARWorldMap.self, 
                                                                   from: mapData) 
    else { 
        throw ARError(.invalidWorldMap) 
    }
    return worldMap
}
```

#### Sixth approach

In ARKit, [ARGeoTrackingConfiguration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/tracking_geographic_locations_in_ar) is implemented with the help of another module – MapKit module. So now you can use a pre-defined GPS data.

```
func session(_ session: ARSession, didAdd anchors: [ARAnchor]) {
   
    for geoAnchor in anchors.compactMap({ $0 as? ARGeoAnchor }) {

        arView.scene.addAnchor(Entity.placemarkEntity(for: geoAnchor)
    }
}
```