# ARKit and LiDAR

Tags: arkit, realitykit, lidar

I've just read the great article from Andy (Reconstruction with a LiDAR scanner). Thanks. At the moment there is not much documentation on this subject (ARKit, RealityKit and LiDAR). In the article I saw the line: "Room’s lighting conditions are now absolutely unimportant". I am working on an app where I can place 3D (.usdz) models and store it. What I see is that when I create a scene and save it when there is enough light, it will not work well when it is dark (and vice versa). Do I need to change some settings? I thought that by using a LiDAR scanner it will make no sense if it is light or dark when you place/reload your AR experience.

Best regards,

Marc

Answer (score 0):

It depends, @DikkeSnoek.

When you're intending to save an ARWorldMap or save 3D scene with textures (if you know how to save textures, of course), then the quality of the lighting is important. However, in case you are going to physically interact with objects in a poorly lit room, or going to detect planes, for such cases – devices with LiDAR are much more practical than without it.

Comment: Hello Andy, thanks. I only want to save the WorldMap. The simple models (tags) will be anchored after loading the map. But when I load the map, sometimes it doesn't work and you see nothing. Saving and loading multiple anchors is also quiet a challenge (Anchor Entities and ARAnchors). There is not much documentation on this and I think that you are one of the few who has knowledge about this. Do you probably have more information or demo code? Thanks in advance, Marc

Comment: You can read about ARWorldMap (and look at sample code) here – https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/data_management/saving_and_loading_world_data and look at my post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63730554/how-do-i-save-and-load-arworldmap-in-swiftui-app/64302711#64302711

Comment: Thanks Andy. I've studied this links (and many more) a few weeks ago. I've found a very interesting one from Gaoping who ported the Apple demo (Saving and Loading World Data) to ARKit/Realitykit: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/651900 Unfortunately it's not based on the new LiDAR technology. I am still searching and learning. I think that I do something wrong. Sometimes I can reproduce my saved AR experience, sometimes not, wierd.