# What's the difference between ARAnchor and AnchorEntity?

Tags: augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

I'm currently doing some experiments with RealityKit.

I've been looking at some sample code, and I'm a bit confused about the differences between `ARAnchor` and `AnchorEntity`, and when to use one over the other.

So far I know that:

- Both are anchors that describes a position in the real world.
- `AnchorEntity` can also have other `Entity`'s as children, so you can add model objects directly to the anchor. You can't do this with `ARAnchor`, you have to add model objects "manually" to the `rootNode`, and use the position of the anchor the place it correctly.
- In the documentation it says that ARKit uses the added `ARAnchor` to optimize the tracking in the area around the anchor. The documentation for `AnchorEntity` does not specify this.

Right now I add a `AnchorEntity` to the session as a "root node", since it's simpler to use, so that I can simply add models as children directly to this anchor. But then I also add a `ARAnchor`, located at the same position, to the scene's anchors, to enhance tracking around this point. **Is this nececary?**

#### Q: Anyone can help me clarify the differences, and use cases of these two?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

*Updated: November 26, 2023*.

---

#### ARAnchor vs AnchorEntity

`ARAnchor` and `AnchorEntity` classes were both made for the same divine purpose – to tether 3D models to your real-world objects.

RealityKit `AnchorEntity` greatly extends the capabilities of ARKit `ARAnchor`. The most important difference between these two is that `AnchorEntity` automatically tracks a real world target, but `ARAnchor` needs `session(...)` instance methods when you use RealityKit (or `renderer(...)` instance methods if you use SceneKit) to accomplish it. Take into consideration that the collection of `ARAnchors` is stored in the ARSession object and the collection of `AnchorEntities` is stored in the Scene.

In addition, generating ARAchors requires a manual [Session config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61045268/arkit-how-to-use-arimagetrackingconfiguration-with-arfacetrackingconfiguration/61060025#61060025), while generating AnchorEntities requires minimal developer's involvement.

Hierarchical differences of iOS AR scenes:

[image]

The main advantage of RealityKit is the ability to use different AnchorEntities at the same time, such as `.plane`, `.body` or `.object`. There's `automaticallyConfigureSession` instance property in RealityKit. When enabled, the `ARView` automatically runs an `ARSession` with a config that will get updated depending on your camera mode and scene anchors. When disabled, the session needs to be run manually with your own config.

```
arView.automaticallyConfigureSession = true           // default
```

In ARKit, as you know, you can run just one config in the current session: World, Body, or Geo. There is an exception in ARKit, however - you can run two configs together - FaceTracking and WorldTracking (one of them has to be a **driver**, and the other one – **driven**).

```
let config = ARFaceTrackingConfiguration()
config.isWorldTrackingEnabled = true
arView.session.run(config)
```

Apple Developer documentation says:

> In RealityKit framework you use an `AnchorEntity` instance as the root of an entity hierarchy, and add it to the **`anchors collection`** for a Scene instance. This enables ARKit to place the anchor entity, along with all of its hierarchical descendants, into the real world. In addition to the components the anchor entity inherits from the `Entity` class, the anchor entity also conforms to the `HasAnchoring` protocol, giving it an `AnchoringComponent` instance.

`AnchorEntity` has three building blocks:

- ***Transform component***  (transformation matrix containing translate, rotate and scale)
- ***Synchronization component***  (entity's synchronization data for multiuser experience)
- ***Anchoring component***  (allows choose a type of anchor – `world`, `body` or `image`)

All entities have `Synchronization component` that helps organise **collaborative sessions**.

[image]

In RealityKit for iOS, `AnchorEntity` object has the eleven specific anchor types for eleven different scenarios (but remember that in RealityKit for macOS you can only work with two types of anchors – `AnchorEntity(world: .zero)` and `AnchorEntity(.camera)`):

- ARAnchor

  - helps implement 10 ARKit anchors, including ARGeoAnchor and ARAppClipCodeAnchor
- body
- camera
- face
- image
- raycastResult
- object
- plane
- world
- head

  - *(works in visionOS only)*
- hand

  - *(works in visionOS only)*

You're able to simultaneously use both objects `ARAnchor` and `AnchorEntity` in your app.

You can find more info on `ARAnchor` and  `AnchorEntity`, in this [THIS POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52893075/what-is-aranchor-exactly/52899502#52899502).

Comment: Thank you for very good explanation! But what about this: _"In the documentation it says that ARKit uses the added ARAnchor to optimize the tracking in the area around the anchor. The documentation for AnchorEntity does not specify this."_ ? Will AnchorEntity also do this optimization, or should I add both anchor types at the location my object will be placed to achieve best results?

Comment: (Sorry @eivindml, I haven't noticed your comment earlier) You do not need to add both types of anchors in your scene. You need just one type: ARKit's ARAnchor or RealityKit's AnchorEntity. Anchors from both modules not only optimise the tracking but also make objects pinned to them more stable.

Comment: Do you know if when initializing an AnchorEntity with the constructor  AnchorEntity(anchor: ARAnchor) if the AnchorEntity follows ARAnchor updates?

Comment: Hi @Nativ, yes it follows when you use `session()` methods for ARAnchor.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @AndyFedoroff. Which methods do you mean? once you add a new ARAnchor you cannot change it, just monitor its updates or removal from the session

Comment: session(_:didUpdate:)