# ARKit – How to use ARImageTrackingConfiguration with ARFaceTrackingConfiguration?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

I have built an app that uses image tracking and swaps flat images. I am also using people occlusion (now) so people can get photos in front of those images. I really want this app to have a selfie mode, so people can take their own pictures in front of image swapped areas.

I'm reading the features on ARKit 3.5, but as far as I can tell, the only front-facing camera support is with `ARFaceTrackingConfiguration`, which doesn't support image tracking. `ARImageTrackingConfiguration` and `ARWorldTrackingConfiguration` only use the back camera.

Is there any way to make a selfie mode with people occlusion (and image tracking) using the front-facing camera?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### About ARConfigurations

The answer is `NO`, you can't use any ARConfiguration except `ARFaceTrackingConfiguration` for front camera. Although, you can simultaneously use `ARFaceTrackingConfiguration` on the front camera and `ARWorldTrackingConfiguration` on the rear camera. This allows users interact with AR content in the rear camera using their face as certain controller.

Look at [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arconfiguration) docs page to find out what config to what camera (rear or front) corresponds to.

Here's a table containing ARKit 5.0 eight tracking configurations:

| ARConfiguration | What Camera? |
| --- | --- |
| ARWorldTrackingConfiguration | Rear |
| ARBodyTrackingConfiguration | Rear |
| AROrientationTrackingConfiguration | Rear |
| ARImageTrackingConfiguration | Rear |
| ARFaceTrackingConfiguration | FRONT |
| ARObjectScanningConfiguration | Rear |
| ARPositionalTrackingConfiguration | Rear |
| ARGeoTrackingConfiguration | Rear |

#### Simultaneous World and Face configs

To use driven World Tracking depending on driver Face Tracking use the following code:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    
    guard ARFaceTrackingConfiguration.isSupported,
          ARFaceTrackingConfiguration.supportsWorldTracking
    else {
        fatalError("We can't do face tracking")
    }        
    let config = ARFaceTrackingConfiguration()
    config.isWorldTrackingEnabled = true
    sceneView.session.run(config)
}
```

Or you can use Face Tracking as a secondary configuration:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    
    let config = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
    
    if !ARWorldTrackingConfiguration.supportsUserFaceTracking {
        print("NOT SUPPORTED")
    } else {
        config.userFaceTrackingEnabled = true
    }
    sceneView.session.run(config)
}
```

Pay attention that both properties are available on iOS 13+.

```
var userFaceTrackingEnabled: Bool { get set }

var isWorldTrackingEnabled: Bool { get set }
```

#### P.S.

At the moment (15th March 2024), `.userFaceTrackingEnabled = true` doesn't work on iPads 2020. Apple officially reports this in the [Configure and Start the Session](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arkit_in_ios/content_anchors/combining_user_face-tracking_and_world_tracking) section (read the comments to the code):

`2020 iPads do not support user face-tracking while world tracking.`

Comment: How to simultaneously use ARFaceTrackingConfiguration on the front and ARWorldTrackingConfiguration on the rear camera? Can you please post a sample for that?

Comment: Thank you! Also, does iPad Pro-2020 support this simultaneous usage of front and back cameras? Do all ARKit supported devices support this feature?

Comment: 100%, if device has a TrueDepth sensor. But I haven't tried devices without TrueDepth.

Comment: I am getting a strange issue. When I have Face tracking configuration as primary and World tracking configuration as Secondary, it works. But when I have world tracking configuration as primary and face tracking as secondary, it says "Unsupported AR Configuration". I am trying this in iPad Pro 4th gen model. Is there anything i am missing here?

Comment: iOS version is 14.6.

Comment: That's wierd but iPhone X (with iOS 14.7.1) catches the same error. I'll try it later on iPad Pro Gen 4.

Comment: @yaali you're right. `userFaceTrackingEnabled` instance property doesn't work on iPad Pro Gen 4 as well. Very strange issue((((. I hope Apple will fix it.

Comment: Hi Vidhya, have you tried `userFaceTrackingEnabled` property in iOS 16 or 17?