# Can I use RealityKit with App Playground?

Tags: swiftui, realitykit

I would like to build an Augmented Reality App using App Playground. Can I build it using RealityKit framework?

[image]

I've already imported RealityKit and created ARViewContainer, but it showed error like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You must add to your code the second compulsory [UIViewRepresentable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/uiviewrepresentable) protocol's stub – [updateUIView(_:context:)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72725585/reality-composer-not-importing-correctly-into-realitykit/72728572#72728572) instance method. The content of this method can be empty.

```
public protocol UIViewRepresentable : View where Self.Body == Never {
    
    @MainActor func makeUIView(context: Self.Context) -> Self.UIViewType

    @MainActor func updateUIView(_ uiView: Self.UIViewType, 
                                  context: Self.Context)
}
```