# Is it possible to track a face and render it in RealityKit ARView?

Tags: swift, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

Apple document says you can set `userFaceTrackingEnabled` to simultaneous front and back camera. After add `ARView` and setting configuration correctly, i can confirm that `ARSessionDelegate` functions will be called normally like below:

```
func session(_ session: ARSession, didAdd anchors: [ARAnchor]) {
    for anchor in anchors where anchor is ARFaceAnchor {
        // triggerd
    }
}

func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate anchors: [ARAnchor]) {
    for anchor in anchors where anchor is ARFaceAnchor {
        // triggerd
    }
}
```

So now i have `ARFaceAnchor` object, what should i do next? Is it possible to render this `ARFaceAnchor` using RealityKit? Or can only be rendered by SceneKit? Because all examples on internet are implemented using SceneKit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you wanna use `RealityKit` rendering technology you should use its own anchors.

So, for RealityKit **face tracking experience** you just need:

```
AnchorEntity(AnchoringComponent.Target.face)
```

And you don't even need `session(_:didAdd:)` and `session(_:didUpdate:)` instance methods in case you're using Reality Composer scene.

If you prepare a scene in Reality Composer `.face` type of anchor is available for you at start. Here's how non-editable hidden Swift code in `.reality` file looks like:

```
public static func loadFace() throws -> Facial.Face {

    guard let realityFileURL = Foundation.Bundle(for: Facial.Face.self).url(forResource: "Facial", 
                                                                          withExtension: "reality") 
    else {
        throw Facial.LoadRealityFileError.fileNotFound("Facial.reality")
    }

    let realityFileSceneURL = realityFileURL.appendingPathComponent("face", isDirectory: false)
    let anchorEntity = try Facial.Face.loadAnchor(contentsOf: realityFileSceneURL)
    return createFace(from: anchorEntity)
}
```

> If you need a more detailed info about anchors, please read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52893075/what-is-aranchor-exactly/52899502#52899502).

**P.S.**

But, at the moment, there's one unpleasant problem – if you're using a scene built in Reality Composer, you can use only one type of anchor at a time (`horizontal`, `vertical`, `image`, `face`, or `object`). Hence, if you need to use `ARWorldTrackingConfig` along with `ARFaceTrackingConfig` – don't use Reality Composer scenes. I'm sure this situation will be fixed in the nearest future.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, it cannot be done by Reality Kit, As i read documentation of face tracking, i could not find anything about tracking with Reality Kit. But you may use SceneKit and also SpriteKit.  Please check this document.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/tracking_and_visualizing_faces

This sentence also took my attention.

> This sample uses ARSCNView to display 3D content with SceneKit, but
>   you can also use SpriteKit or build your own renderer using Metal (see
>   ARSKView and Displaying an AR Experience with Metal).

Comment: Yeah, I also searched all the documents i could find, but find nothing. Apple recommends RealityKit so much, I can hardly imagine that it doesn't support it!