# How ARFaceAnchor determine to vertices indices?

Tags: swift, machine-learning, deep-learning, arkit, arcore

I have used ARKit face tracking. By using it, I can get face feature points

```
x=faceAnchor.geometry.vertices[638][0]
  
y=faceAnchor.geometry.vertices[638][1]

z=faceAnchor.geometry.vertices[638][2]
```

Some simple question come to my mind.
That is "How ARFaceAnchor determine to vertices indices?"
I serached many URLs([apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arfaceanchor),[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52893075/what-is-aranchor-exactly?rq=1&newreg=d61e9d0fc5f24ba8aa13803f12c7f858)),but I couldn't find the truth.

I thought like the dlib, machine learning is used?
Where can I find the imformation about that(how calculate face vetices indices)?
ARKit's face vertices are more accurate than ARcore
what difference methods are used?

Comment: what points do you need from face and how you are using that?

Comment: I am interested in “how this library finds 1220 feature points from face”. I want to know the method.     Like this method was used?(https://www.hindawi.com/journals/wcmc/2018/9729014/)   . Apple’s face ar anchor’s geometry has many feature points(1220) compare with other library(arcore, dlib). I want to know How apple’s library detecta face geometry and how to make the library.