# ARCore + RealityKit – Cloud Anchors and AnchorEntities

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, arcore, realitykit

I need to implement ARCore Cloud Anchors with RealityKit in iOS swift app, I have read google doc and downloaded a GitHub https://github.com/kboy-silvergym/ARCore-Swift-Sampler project in Swift for ARCore and cloud anchor but not got success, can anyone suggest me a tutorial for ARCore Cloud Anchors implementation in iOS Swift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a working version of ARKit app (I suspect that you wrote Swift app, taking into account everything that were in Objective-C build), then it'll not be difficult for you to feed any ARAnchor to the [AnchorEntity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52893075/what-is-aranchor-exactly/52899502#52899502) initializer (*take a look at faceAnchor code snippet in AnchorEntity section*).

```
AnchorEntity(anchor: ARAnchor(transform: .init(diagonal: .one)))
```

Remember that RealityKit anchors are stored in the Scene, and ARKit anchors – in running session.